# How would I import Pillow for python

Tags: python-3.x

I've tried everything from other questions but nothing seems to work. It’s installed on this computer, it’s just I can’t import it!
Here’s what I wrote:

```
from PIL import Image
#Open image using Image module
im = Image.open("/home/****/Pictures/Screenshot from 2021-08-03 18-21-59.png")
#Show actual Image
im.show()
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: And how exactly did you install Pillow?

Comment: Yea we need some clarification on how you installed Pillow and if you are using any kind of virtual environment. This seems like a matter of not having the right environment selected.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.